# Xcode remove touch event images?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiimageview, uitouch

I'm using this code to display random images on the screen.

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

    UIImageView *cloud = [[UIImageView alloc] 
                               initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"spit.png"]];

    cloud.center = CGPointMake(random() % 250, random() % 400); //Random place
    [cloud setAlpha:1];
    [self.view addSubview:cloud];
    [cloud release];

    cloud.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300); 

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"cloddy" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5f];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];

    // Size when done
    cloud.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 75, 75); 
    cloud.center = location;
    [UIView commitAnimations]; 
}
```

after a couple of touches the screen gets kinda full. How do I remove them inside another IBAction? And why does the animation always start in the upper left corner even though I'm using random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the only subviews that have been added to your view are `clouds`,

```
- (IBAction)clearClouds:(id)sender{
    [[[self view] subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
}
```

The cloud is always starting at the upper left because this line: `cloud.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);`resets its origin to 0,0. Move `cloud.center = CGPointMake(random() % 250, random() % 400);` below the line where you set the cloud's frame and you should be all set.